# How to align two radio buttons horizontally in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic3

I am trying to align two radio buttons in single row or horizontally in Ionic 3 as shown in below image.

[image]

**html**

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-row radio-group >
      <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        Batch Medium
      </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
       <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>English</ion-label>
        <ion-radio >English</ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Bilingual</ion-label>
        <ion-radio>Bilingual</ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>    
    </ion-item>
```

After trying this code I am getting blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

That's like verbose ugly :)

Here is my take

- The Looks

[image]

or

[image]

- The HTML
  [image]
- The CSS
  [image]
- The code behind
  [image]
  [image]

There is more tweaking you can do like with flexbox

The least you invest in any framework the better :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Tryout like below code.

```
 <ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="batchmedium">
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            Batch Medium*
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label> English </ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="English"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
           <ion-label> Bilingual </ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="Bilingual"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

review this link for more details http://plnkr.co/edit/AdFPOUaufyFYXqBxNiGg?p=preview

Comment: Almost there.When i view in mobile screen both radio button breaks in two line otherwise in normal computer screen its fine on ionic serve.